# Differentiate between Symfony spooled email types in a cron job/scheduled task

Tags: php, symfony, email, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a Symfony application that sends emails when users register/recover passwords. It uses [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) to do so, but I've overwritten the translations and added my own. The emails are being sent, but from the client's browser, thing which I don't want.

I've looked into [spooling](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/email/spool.html#spool-using-a-file) and everything works fine, the emails are saved in files and upon running the command, the emails are being sent.

The problem comes in me having two types of emails:

- instant emails, that have to be sent almost instantly, because the
  information is required immediately: when user registers or recovers
  his password, he needs his confirmation link. Also receiving a
  private message from within my app could send a message to notify him
  faster.
- bulk or mass-emails, for instance when the admin sends a lot of emails to all or certain groups of users. A cron job would send these
  in groups of 10 emails every 10 minutes.

The problem is that no matter what email type it is, it is added in the spool, and if the cron job just ran, the users registering, for example, will get their emails only after ~10 minutes.

If in that time span, 50 emails were added to the spool, and then another user were to register, he would get his email in around an hour, since he must wait for 5 cron jobs to execute for the 50 emails before executing his.

A solution would be to increase the emails sent and to lower the time between the cron jobs, but that still won't fully solve the problem.

Is there a way to have different spooled emails, or to somehow differentiate between email types?